# How to break the content in two parts to use php the_content1 and php the_content2

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic

I have a chunk of content in a textarea that I can call dynamically to the front by using `<php the_content ?>` See full code below.

The problem is, I dont have an assigned area for the image. (I'm open to options to create one but I think it will be too much effort), anyway, is there anything I can do (JQuery / JS is fine) that I can call the image to fill the: `<?php echo $the_content['image'] ?>` that you see in my code, which obviously does not work? Meanwhile leaving the actual text part or rest of the content separate.

I am attaching an illustration for a more visual idea of what I am looking for

[image]

Here is the entire code for that section

```
 <section class="box classes-box" id="classes_box"><!-- Section Events -->
  <div class="container light-grey-background">
       <div class="row">                    
            <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                 <div class="boxing-classes" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $the_content['image'] ?>')">
                      <div class="classes">
                           <nav class="classes-nav">
                                <ul class="clean-list toggle-list clearfix">
                                    <?php foreach($slides as $i => $slide): ?>
                                        <li class="classes-menu-item ">
                                            <input type="radio" id="toggle-<?php echo $slide['post']->ID; ?>" name="toggle-helper" autocomplete="off">
                                            <label for="toggle-<?php echo $slide['post']->ID; ?>"><?php echo get_the_title( $slide['post']->ID ) ?></label>                                                
                                        </li>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </ul>
                           </nav>
                      </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6 no-padding ">
                 <?php foreach($slides as $i => $slide): ?>
                      <div class="classes-content-block" id="classes_content_<?php echo $slide['post']->ID ?>" style="display:none;">
                           <header class="padding white-background">
                               <h2 class="entry-header black-background"><?php echo get_the_title( $slide['post']->ID ) ?></h2>
                           </header>

                           <div class="entry-content padding">
                               <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $slide['post']->post_content); ?>

                               <?php  if ( !empty( $slide['options']['button'] )): ?>
                                    <div class="white-background">
                                        <a class="read-more text-center red-black-hover" href="<?php echo $slide['options']['button']['link'] ? $slide['options']['button']['link'] : '#'; ?>"><?php echo  $slide['options']['button']['link_text'] ? $slide['options']['button']['link_text'] : 'View Timeline' ; ?></a>
                                    </div>
                               <?php endif; ?>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>

              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, what people do is to create a [Shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) that will produce the desired HTML, something like:

> `[image-block src="apple-touch-icon.png" class="all-imgs" id="my-img"]The content[/image-block]`

This would be the shortcode:

```php
add_shortcode( 'image-block', function( $atts, $content) {
    return sprintf(
        '<div class="left"><img src="%1$s" class="%2$s" id="%3$s"></div><div class="right">%4$s</div>',
        $atts['src'],
        $atts['class'],
        $atts['id'],
        $content
    );
});
```

And this the output:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: This is actually a good thing because it separates it into a shortcode, But I still can't use it dynamically. I'm more interested in being able to call the image the user types in the content and use it in a separate div that is already loaded somewhere else by making reference to the variable that stores the image not the image itself.

Comment: I think that making it dynamically would require some nasty regex to parse `the_content`. Alternative routes: grab image insertions on the post and convert it into shortcode or raw html; add a tinymce button (or a meta box) that emulates image insertion and does your thing.

Answer (score -1):

See CSS property FLOAT : left|right

```
<div id=container class="clearfix">
    <div class="image-wrapper" style="float:left;max-width:50%;padding:0;margin:0">
        <img src="images/mypicture.jpg" alt="" class="rwd-image" id="mymage">
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper" style="float:left;max-width:50%;padding:0;margin:0">
       <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```